# SSIS Data Truncation error

Tags: ssis

I am having an issue in SSIS Please help me to resolve.

In table one column having length varchar(8000).
I created one ssis package to push data from oledb source to excel destination using data conversion transformation.But the total length of data not pushed into excel data truncation occurring.Can you please help on this how to overcome this issue.

Comment: I think you need to be sure that your destination is DT_NTEXT in datatype

Comment: Thank you plaidDK for sharing your information before only i tried that DT_NTEXT,but the data is getting truncating in Excel destination.